# Where does Tauc's relation come from? Why is the method valid?

Tags: electronic-band-theory

$$ (\alpha h \nu)^{1/r}=A(h\nu - E_g) $$
(1/r represents the nature of transition)

We were replicating an experiment from a paper in our physics lab, wherein we used the above equation and considered the intercept of the linear region in [Tauc's plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauc_plot) gives the bandgap. However, no where it was mentioned why the relation or the method holds (the experiment was about improving the results obtained from Tauc's method). I looked for it everywhere and failed to find an explanation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Tauc plot equation comes from the quantum-mechanical transition rate, where the trasition rate is calculated by Fermi's Golden Rule.